# .Net persistency of object on WebApplication

Tags: .net, object, server, persistence

I'm running my WebApplication on IISServer.
I've created static class:

```
public class JMSInformationGetterUAT
{

    private static String userName = "123";
    private static String password = "321";

    public static String runningJMS = "";

    private static Admin adminConnection = null;

     public static void Init()
    {
        try
        {
            String serverUrl = "tcp://localhost:1232";

            adminConnection.CommandTimeout = 500;
            adminConnection = new Admin(serverUrl, userName, password);
            runningEMS = "JMS1Instance";

        }
        catch
        {
            EMSCriticalFailure = true;
        }
    }   

}
```

and added  it to Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        JMSInformationGetterUAT.Init();
    }
```

... on page when I'm using `JMSInformationGetterUAT.RunningJMS` I only get error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

On JMS side (that application is for quick monitoring) I see 1 ms connection and then none - but in object `adminConnection` filled by `Init()` method should keeping connection. Wen I refer to this object it is also empty...

So why this object is not persistent? It has static prefix...

please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting a the property CommandTimeout of the adminConnection before you instantiate new Admin.

adminConnection = new Admin (...)

needs to occur before you can access any non static properties.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed code a little after suggestion from Fran.
Now it works:

```
public class JMSInformationGetterUAT{

private static String userName = "123";
private static String password = "321";

public static String runningJMS = "";

private static Admin adminConnection = new Admin("localhost:1234", userName, password);

 public static void Init()
{
   //some other logic i needed
}   }
```